# How can I get more information on why my MySQL connection gets ECONNREFUSED?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to use `promise-mysql` (node module) to connect to a MySQL instance, but it fails with `ECONNREFUSED`. Here's the entire error:

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.6:3306
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-mysql/lib/connection.js:18:33)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-mysql/lib/connection.js:52:9
    at Promise._execute (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
    at new Promise (/usr/src/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
    at new connection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-mysql/lib/connection.js:51:12)
    at Object.exports.createConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/promise-mysql/index.js:6:12)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/test/default-parameters.test.js:9:10)
    at callFn (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:345:21)
    at Hook.Runnable.run (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:337:7)
    at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:309:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:339:5)
    at runCallback (timers.js:666:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:639:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:611:5)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.18.0.6',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true }
```

I have no idea why this is happening. How can I get more information on why the connection is refused?

With "more information" I mean stuff like:

- Is this because of invalid credentials?
- Is the host unreachable?
- Is the host reachable but the MySQL server down?
- Are we hitting a MySQL connection limit?
- Are there gnomes in my computer trying to make me mad?

Answer (score 1):

1. Is this because of invalid credentials? No, that would result in an [access denied](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_access_denied_error) error message.
2. Are we hitting a MySQL connection limit? No, that would result in [too many connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) error message.
3. Is the host unreachable? Is the host reachable but the MySQL server down? Yes, any of the two can cause this error message. The error message means that the client could not even reach the server (this error is generated by the client, the previous two error messages are generated by MySQL server).

As MySQL documentation on [can't connect to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html) says:

> The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the one configured on the server.

Unfortunately, there is no way of telling based on the error message which of these caused the error, you need to manually investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

I think host reachable but the MySQL server down.

check your MySQL server host and port is correct and check can able to access in local such as MySQL in terminal.